# How to send a plain text email in Laravel 8 without using a blade?

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-8

How can I send a plain text email in Laravel 8 without using a blade?

All our email messages and templates are stored in a database, so using a blade is not applicable to us.  I just want to pass in text to send.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```php
Mail::raw('This is a simple text', function ($m) {
  $m->to('toemail@abc.com')->subject('Email Subject');
});
```

Don't forget to include

```php
use Mail;
```

Comment: Thank you, Aniket, but if I do it this way, I can't use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::assertSent(...), because assertSent(...) requires a Mailable object, and your solution doesn't use a Mailable object.  In older versions of Laravel, your answer would be correct, but I would like to do it the Laravel 8 way.

Comment: @Magmatic - That requirement should have been in your question when you posted it. If you have specific requirements, clearly write that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing, and I think it's a good solution.

I created a generic Mailable class called app\Mail\Message.php.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Message extends Mailable {
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $theSubject;
    private $htmlBody;
    private $fromAddress;
    private $theAttachments;
    private $replyToEmail;

    public function __construct($subject, $htmlBody, $fromAddress, $replyTo=null, $attachments=null) {
        $this->theSubject = $subject;
        $this->htmlBody = $htmlBody;
        $this->fromAddress = $fromAddress;
        $this->theAttachments = $attachments;
        $this->replyToEmail = $replyTo;
    }

    public function getBody() {
        return $this->htmlBody;
    }


    public function build() {
        $this->subject($this->theSubject);
        $this->from($this->fromAddress);
        $this->html($this->htmlBody);

        if ($this->replyToEmail != null) {
            $this->replyTo($this->replyToEmail);
        }

        // more info here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#attachments
        if ($this->theAttachments != null) {
            foreach($this->theAttachments as $attachment) {
                if (is_array($attachment)) {
                    $this->attach($attachment[0], [                     // $attachment[0] = temp file path
                        'as'    =>  (isset($attachment[1]) ? $attachment[1]:null),  // $attachment[1] = filename
                        'mime'  =>  (isset($attachment[2]) ? $attachment[2]:null),  // $attachment[2] = mime type
                    ]);
                } else {
                    $this->attach($attachment);     // $attachment = temp file path
                }
            }
        }
        
        return $this;
    }
}
```

To send an email, I do this:

```
$message = new Message($subject, $fullBody, $fromAddress, $replyTo, $attachments);
Mail::to($address)->send($message);
```

To test sending email, I do this:

```
Mail::fake();
Mail::assertNothingSent();

// do something that sends an email...

Mail::assertSent(Message::class, function($email) {
    $token = // get something that should be found in the body

    $email->build();
    $allGood = true;
    $allGood &= $email->subject === 'Password Recovery';
    $allGood &= str_contains($email->getBody(), $token);
    return $allGood;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't specifically address the question, though. OP attempted to send plain text emails, not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better of creating a Notification class that sends via mail. You can generate a notification with
`php artisan make:notification OrderShipped`
And by default its `via` method will send by mail, and will use Laravels default mail templates. In the toMail you can send whatever is needed. Then for your tests you can do:

```php
public function testUserGetNotifiedIfOrderShipped())
{
    Notification::fake();

    // Hit some endpoints thats will send notification

    // Assert Admin gets notification
    Notification::assertSentTo(User::first(), OrderShipped::class);
}
```